# How do I get the timestamp for my date

Tags: wordpress, timestamp

The current code below returns my current local time in wordpress and the result looks like this. 2013-07-29 13:45:42

I need to convert this to a timestamp format. What is the answer please?

```
echo date_i18n( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', current_time( 'timestamp', 0 ) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Come to find out I really just needed the actual date and not a timestamp to achieve my goal. So using this gives you wordpress current local time that is set on the settings page in the admin panel.

```
date_i18n('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: For WordPress your saved current timestamp format for posts is simply date('YmdHis');

Answer (score 4):

The PHP [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function might work.

```
$timestamp = strtotime('2013-07-29 13:45:42');
```

**EDIT**
Here is your use case

```
$current_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ## Get current date
$timestamp = strtotime($current_date); ## Get timestamp of current date
echo $timestamp; ## Print timestamp
```

Comment: Can you give me full example using my code? or am I missing something? sorta new to timestamping

Comment: Sure thing. Just added it to my answer.

Comment: True this does work, however for some reason the date_i18n when added does not give the true timestamp for the local time set in wordpress. When echoed simply as above it does though. What am I missing?